# Can somebody give an example of realization of "Decorator" pattern in Java Core?

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator

I want to know where in Java Core "Decorator" pattern is realized. Can somebody give an example? I'm in the first place interested in example from java core, but if you know some realizations from popular frameworks - you're welcome! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A classic example could be the [`BufferedInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html). It can wrap any other `InputStream`, delegate the reads to it, but adds the functionality to buffer those reads.